# Pseudo element strange behaviour with img

Tags: html, css

Trying to make information about image below it. But have A problem... Pseudo element is not visible..

```
<img info="hey guys" src="http://i024.radikal.ru/1211/4c/809c7c2dfa74.jpg">
<div info="I'm working, but I'm inside the block"></div>

div {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: yellow;
}
div[info]::after, img[info]::after {
    content: attr(info);
    display: block;
    margin: 3px;
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f62H/8/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img` elements can't have pseudo elements, because they can't have children—`::before` is inserted within the element. It would look like this:

```
<img><before></img>
```

Or at least itt isn't defined by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements are appended/prepended to the element's contents. Since an `<img>` (and an `<input>` for instance) has no contents, it cannot have pseudo elements applied on it.